# js.erb file is not fired up when try upload a image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, fancybox, simple-form

I have inside a fancybox box this form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@message, :remote => true, :html => {:multipart => true}, :url => { :controller => "users/messages", :action => "create"} ) do |f| %>
 <%= f.error_notification %>
 <%= f.input :subject, :input_html => { :maxlength => 500} %>
 <%= f.input :message_image, :as => :file %>
 <%= f.button :submit, t('.send_message'), :class => 'btn-large btn-primary', "data-disable-with" => t('.send_message'), :confirm => t('.sure_send_message') %>
<% end %>
```

This is my create action:

```
def create
 @message = Message.new(params[:message])
 respond_to do |format|
  if @message.save
   format.js { render :partial => "users/messages/templates/sent_by_user/create" }
  else
   format.js { render :partial => "users/messages/templates/sent_by_user/nosave" }
  end
 end 
end
```

The files `create.js.erb` or `nosave.js.erb` file is working fine if I don't try upload a image

If I try  upload a image this files is not rendered.

However in my log I can see:

```
Processing by Users::MessagesController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"message"=>{"message_image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xf7a85c8 @original_filename="cara_enfadada.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"message[message_image]\"; filename=\"cara_enfadada.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20121015-21710-6oxtn2>>, "subject"=>"estrella de neutronessssssssssss"}, "commit"=>"Enviar mensaje", "utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"mfSsl0HafWoW86YiO2Hj7zMepAITZlHHBtUqW0wzubU=", "remotipart_submitted"=>"true", "X-Requested-With"=>"IFrame", "X-Http-Accept"=>"text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01", "locale"=>"es"}
```

and

```
Rendered users/messages/templates/sent_by_user/_nosave.js.erb (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 498ms (Views: 1.5ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
```

On google chrome console I get the next alert:

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/javascript:
```

**I'm using remotipart gem but I dont find the error...
Where is the error?
Thank you**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will never execute the js.erb because one can just directly upload a file(image in your case) using ajax

You might want to think of **remotipart** or **pupload** or **jqueryfile_upload** or **uplodify**  to acheive

I'm sure that remotipart use iframe

Pupload use runtime support html5 or flash

uploadify use flash

not sure of jqueryfile_upload as never tried it

Good luck